# CSS Margin trouble with Chrome?

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

Following is the css code for body element. The problem is that if i set width to 100% then there is no margin on right side, only margin comes on left side. i tested on chrome.Also if i 
do anything like 1000px the problem occurs

```
body {
        background:#ff00ff ;        
        margin: 50px;
        width:100%;
        border:5px ;
        border : dotted;  
}
```

Comment: Just remove `width: 100%`, there's no need for it.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `width: 100%;` and it should be fine.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m4LEa/)

Comment: But why does it happens ?